# Kubernetes event logs

Tags: kubernetes

As a part of debug i need to track down events like pod creation and removal. in my kubernetes set up I am using logging level 5.

Kube api server, scheduler, controller, etcd are running on master node and the minion nodes is running kubelet and docker.

I am using `journalctl` to get K8s logs on master node as well on worker node. On worker node i can see logs from Docker and Kubelet. These logs contain events as i would expect as i create and destroy pods.

However on Master node i dont see any relevant logs which may indicate a pod creation or removal request handling.

**what other logs or method i can use to get such logs from Kubernetes master components  (API server, controller, scheduler, etcd)?**

i have checked the logs from API server, controller, scheduler, etcd pods; they dont seem to have such information.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**System component logs:**

There are two types of system components:

- those that run in a container
- and those that do not run in a container.

For example:

The Kubernetes scheduler and kube-proxy run in a container

The kubelet and container runtime, for example Docker, do not run in containers.

On machines with systemd, the kubelet and container runtime write to journald. If systemd is not present, they write to .log files in the /var/log directory. System components inside containers always write to the /var/log directory, bypassing the default logging mechanism. They use the klog logging library.

**Master components logs:**

Get them from those containers running on master nodes.

```
$ 
$ docker ps | grep apiserver
d6af65a248f1        af20925d51a3                 "kube-apiserver --ad…"   2 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks                              k8s_kube-apiserver_kube-apiserver-minikube_kube-system_177a3eb80503eddadcdf8ec0423d04b9_0
5f0e6b33a29f        k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 2 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks                              k8s_POD_kube-apiserver-minikube_kube-system_177a3eb80503eddadcdf8ec0423d04b9_0
$ 
$ 
$ docker logs -f d6a
```

But all of this approach to logging is just for testing , you should stream all the logs , ( app logs , container logs , cluster level logs , everything) to a centeral logging system such as ELK or EFK.

Comment: Thank you Ijaz i followed your leads and inside kube apiserver container logs I am not finding any relevant log messages which point to pod creation or removal  ..second issue i see is all timestamps are with UTC timezone. Any idea how can i change them to PST?

Comment: you need to configure the logging level for api-server , api servr has lot of logging configuration options that you need to enable first.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/

Comment: One more thing , the information you are looking for maybe in audit log of api server , so you just ecex into api server container and see the audit logs

Comment: i was able to add cutomized log entries in source code and those logs apart from verbosity logs are visible  via  docker logs -f